# Image color invert on button click C#

Tags: c#, .net, image, colors

I'm using WinForms. I got a picturebox which contains an image. On button click I want to invert the colors of this image back and forth. I tried to make the images invert faster by a button click with the code below. The problem I'm having is that I get an error

Error: Where the code says: Parallel.ForEach(rect.SubRectangles <- I get an error: `'Rectangle' does not contain a definition fo subRectangles' and no extension method 'SubRectangles' accepting a first argument of type 'Rectangel' could be found`

2nd error: `Under the IEnumerable<Rectangle>SubRectangles <--- (Extension)IEnumerable<Rectangle>ImageUtility.SubRectangle(this Rectanger,... Extension methods must be defined in a top level static class; ImageUtility is a nested class`.

Another issue I'm having is calling this code into the button click event so it could work. I'm still learning how to program.

```
public static class ImageUtility
{
public static Bitmap Process(Bitmap bmp)
{
    Bitmap retBmp = new Bitmap(bmp);

    var depth = Bitmap.GetPixelFormatSize(bmp.PixelFormat) / 8;
    if (depth < 3) throw new ArgumentException("Image must be at least 24 bpp.");

    var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
    var data = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);

    var buffer = new byte[data.Width * data.Height * depth];

    //copy pixels to buffer
    Marshal.Copy(data.Scan0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    bmp.UnlockBits(data);

    //Process Image
    Parallel.ForEach(rect.SubRectangles(2, 4), r => InvertColor(buffer, r, data.Width, depth));

    //Copy the buffer back to  image
    data = retBmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);
    Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, data.Scan0, buffer.Length);
    retBmp.UnlockBits(data);

    return retBmp;
}

static void InvertColor(byte[] buffer, Rectangle r, int orgWidth, int depth)
{
    for (int i = r.X; i < r.X + r.Width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = r.Y; j < r.Y + r.Height; j++)
        { 
            var offset = ((j * orgWidth) + i) * depth;
            buffer[offset + 0] = (byte)(255 - buffer[offset + 0]);
            buffer[offset + 1] = (byte)(255 - buffer[offset + 1]);
            buffer[offset + 2] = (byte)(255 - buffer[offset + 2]);
        }
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<Rectangle> SubRectangles(this Rectangle r, int dx, int dy)
{
    int incX = (r.Width - r.X) / dx;
    int incY = (r.Height - r.Y) / dy;

    for (int y = r.Y; y < r.Height; y += incY)
    {
        for (int x = r.X; x < r.Width; x += incX)
        {
            yield return new Rectangle(x, y, incX, incY);
        }
    }
}
}

    private void button_Color_Invert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     //TO DO:

    }
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but shouldn't it be `int incX = r.Width / dx;`? Note: `r.Width` is not `r.Right`. It is `r.Right - r.Left`.

Comment: I'm not really sure. I'm still learning. I got this code from a form. Its hard for me to decipher. Originally i had something a lot simpler but it was so slow. i was doing using GetPixel and someone recommened that using LockBit is faster. But I couldn't figure out how to invert images using LockBit. If you have a solution let me know. I'd appreciate it.  @OlivierJacot-Descombes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it compiles for me. Is your  class `ImageUtility` nested in another class? It shouldn't be, because extension methods must be placed in a top level static class. That's what your second error message is saying. The method `SubRectangles` is an extension method, because of the `this` keyword in the parameter list.

class `ImageUtility` should be placed in its own file.

---

```
public static class A // Top level and static
{
    class B // Nested
    {
    }
}
```

See:
- [Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx)

Comment: This might be a silly question but what is a top level static class?

Comment: I'll try again. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: Well then it is nested in your form class. Put it in a separate file. In  Visual Studio, right click the project and select `Add` > `Class` and then enter the name `ImageUtility` and insert the methods above into this new class. Then delete the class from your form.

Comment: Thank you for simplifying it for me

Comment: How do i use the methods when i click on the button on my form. I tried this. ( var bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image); ), and couple other methods but the compiler didn't like it.

Comment: Try `var bmp = ImageUtility.Process((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image);`. The name of the method is `Process`. `Bitmap` is its return type.